# Is it wise to use the paper reference numbers defined in CV in statement of purpose?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, citations, cv, statement-of-purpose

If in my CV I assign to each paper of mine exactly one number, say [1] On ...; [2] On ..., and if I want to introduce my works in my statement of purpose, then is it wise to use these paper reference numbers in my statement of purpose?

Comment: If you write your CV and statement of purpose using LaTeX, then you can use bibtex to handle your citations. I would favour this style.

Comment: @user2768 that doesn't answer the question about if Kurt should re-use those references, or re-print them on the new document.

Comment: @mankoff, yes, you're right, I wasn't clear. I meant, if you write your "CV and statement of purpose using LaTeX [in a single document]." In this case, bibtex would produce a single bibliography at the end of the document. I.e., statement of purpose, CV, bibliography. You may like to add your covering letter too.

Comment: If 1 document requested, then yes, cite the CV part. But usually multiple docs are requested. If 1-page cover letter, 3-page research statement, 2-page teaching statement, 10-page CV, etc. are part of the packet, don't make them hunt down the references on page X of the CV part of the package...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make anyone do extra work. They may not want to (or easily be able to) open a different file to find the reference. Give up part (1/4th?) of a page for references. Don't cram text in the main body, but references could be written with a (slightly) smaller/tighter font size/spacing if necessary.

Comment: Surely this results in duplications of citations, i.e., at the end of the statement of purpose and again at the end of the CV. I'd rather see a single list of citations. 

As I suggested above, I recommend defining a single document for statement of purpose, CV, bibliography, ... this also eliminates the issue of not having the right files.

Comment: At **the end** of the CV? To first approximation, the list of publications _is_ the CV!